# Pullbacks in filtered categories?

Tags: category-theory

A sufficient condition for the inclusion of a full subcategory $\mathsf C\hookrightarrow \mathsf D$ to be cofinal is that:

1. Every object of $\mathsf D$ has an arrow into some object of $\mathsf C$.
2. $\mathsf D$ has <s>pullbacks</s> pushouts.

Pullbacks in poset categories are infima, which means one can calculate directed colimits using convenient subcategories.

I'm wondering whether there is a nice description of pullbacks in filtered categories which would enable simplification of filtered colimits. By 'description' I mean both examples and general existence statements.

Comment: Actually, you can replace condition 2 with "$\mathcal{D}$ is filtered".

Comment: @ZhenLin neat observation. Thanks.